# Ionic Framework "Gestures and Events" not Firing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I've been using the Ionic Framework on a recent project and I'm unable to actually use the inbuilt "Gestures and Events", as described by their docs here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onTouch/

According to their docs, I would assume that the following code should work when dropped into a template:

```
<button on-touch="onTouch()" class="button">Test</button>
<script>function onTouch() {console.log('touched');}</script>
```

The above code is not logging anything to the console. Just for reference, if I were to replace `<button on-touch="onTouch()"` with `<button onClick="onTouch()"` it fires the function.

I'm debugging via my Android device currently, and monitoring the console via the Chrome inspect devices developer feature.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: what version of android?

Comment: Android 5.1.1. I'm not sure that the issue is incompatibility with this version of Android, seeing as how it doesn't work in the iOS emulator either.

Comment: so I have seen some other people have this problem, no idea why though. You could just use a ng-click="onTouch()" to fire events for now. I know it is not idea but it will work